# using explicit with templates, C++

Tags: c++, templates, explicit

i have a question about explicit and templates:

```
template<class T> 
class A {

    class A_Impl {
        T var;

        public:
            explicit A_Impl(T var1) : var(var1), version(1) 
            {
            }

            A_Impl(const A_Impl& a ) : var(a.var), version(1) 
            {
            }

            const A_Impl& operator=(const A_Impl& a)
            {
                var=a.var;++version;return *this;   
            }

            operator T() const { return var; }

            friend class A<T>;
    };

    A_Impl a;

public:
    A(T var): a(var) 
    {
    }

    A_Impl& get() { return a; }
};

void main() {
    A<int> a1(5);
    cout<<"a1 = "<<a1.get()<<endl;

    a1.get()=7;
    cout<<"a1 = "<<a1.get()<<endl;

    a1=13;
    cout<<"a1 = "<<a1.get()<<endl;
}
```

I get en error at `a1.get()=7;` which says no operator "=" matches these operands

Also, if i take explicit word out it will compile, but i dont understand the difference between the `a1.get()` function and `a1=13;` which works fine even with explicit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get en error at a1.get()=7; which says no operator "=" matches these operands

There's no way to convert `7` to a `A_Impl` for `operator=`, because the constructor `A_Impl(T)`, which in this instance is expanded to `A_Impl(int)`, is declared `explicit`.

You can either remove the `explicit` keyword, or explicitly create an `A_Impl` with:

```
a1.get() = A_Impl(7);
```

Alternatively you can also declare a specific `operator=`:

```
const A_Impl& operator=(const T&)
```

for the `A_Impl` class.

---

> Also, if i take explicit word out it will compile, but i dont understand the difference between the a1.get() function and a1=13; which works fine even with explicit.

`a1 = 13` works fine because the template class `A` has a *non-explicit* constructor to `T` (specifically `A(T var)`), which, in this case, match perfect for `T = int`.

---

Also notice that `main` should always return `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You only have declared a copy assignment operator: `const A_Impl& operator=(const A_Impl& a)`,
but not a assignment operator for `T` types: `const A_Impl& operator=(const T& a)`.

If you dont have an `explicit` constructor, your int (`7`) will implecitely converted to a `A_Impl` object which is then assigned to your returned reference.

If your constructor is `explicit` this implecit conversion is not possible anymore (thats what `explicit` actually does), and thus there is no possibility to assign an `int` to a `A_Impl`.
What however would work if your `A_Impl` class is public, is this (the same that happens under the hood if you dont write `explicit`):

```
a1.get() = A_Impl(7);
```